# Restart Java Swing application

Tags: java, macos

I want to introduce update and rollback feature for my Java swing application. First I am trying to use two `jar` files and one will be updating other and exit. 
This attempt was successful, but the problem is that I can't set the icon image for my application for `MAC OS`. The next attempt is used single jar file and use system process to rename the running jar file and run the updated `jar` file. But I not familiar with system commands and I don't know how to integrate these commands with Java application (`ProcessBuilder`).
Is there any solution to set icon for jar files?

`Jarbuddler` is useful but it won't help in my case(Two `jar` file - `Launcher`, `Application`)

Or

Can you please provide a solutuion with "System process". Is there any problem for using the command , ie OS versions?

Please advise.

Comment: Please elaborate, are you trying to set the doc-tile, or the file icon?

Answer (score 0):

The Dock

The com.apple.eawt.Application class includes the following methods for managing your Java application’s Dock icon:

```
public java.awt.Image getDockIconImage()
public void setDockIconImage(java.awt.Image)
public java.awt.PopupMenu getDockMenu()
public void setDockMenu(java.awt.PopupMenu)
public void setDockIconBadge(String)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html